# Form authentication for not authorised user

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee, jdbcrealm

i'm implementing a form based authentication for my web application.

i created some users in the JDBCrealm  on TomEE server and allow only particular users to access the protected jsf pages.

Now authentication works perfectly and if there is a username password mismatch it is redirected to the error page.

the problem i'm facing here is, if i try to login with the user already available in the JDBCrealm who is not authorised to access the protected the page im getting 403 error.

When I come back and try again get to protected pages i can't again login. Is it because information about my login is remembered in session and I have to invalidate session?

Even if I don't login ?

**EDIT:**

i ask about at forum: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-security-TomEE-td4665009.html

and i think its the best answer for my question

Comment: Are you sure you're not just facing page from browser cache? To exclude that, perform a hard refresh.

Comment: What that mean 'hard refresh' ?

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+F5 in browser.

Comment: Which server are you by the way using? You tagged Tomcat and TomEE on the question and you keep talking about Weblogic inside your question. That are 3 completely different servers. What is this?

Comment: i use tomEE, weblogic in my question is some mistake

Comment: Okay, When you delete the session cookie in client side, then it works?

Comment: yes, when i delete session cookie it works, but how to delete session cookie in application?

Comment: This is not expected behavior. If I were you, I would report an issue to TomEE guys.

Comment: why is this 'not expected behavior' ?

Comment: That you can't login anymore across the session after a login fail.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to implement this yourself take a look to something like [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html), it provides most of the options you will need and if you need to extend it is easy as well

Comment: thanks, but i thing its too much for me, i don't have Spring-based applications

Comment: You're not answering the question at all. You're merely recommending a completely different tool. Just post a comment then (or look for a discussion forum or chatbox where you can post this over all place). This is like as posting an answer in a Java programming topic that the asker should be using C# because whatever the asker is trying to achieve is much simpler using that language. This doesn't make sense.